# Android: Error transfer data after click of buttons

Tags: android

Hi there I am new to Android Programming

I am trying to create an application in which, the user clicks button on the first page
the text color in the buttons change color and the change is reflected in another activity page.

To do this I have 
1) one fragment class(BookLockerFragment) which reference to an xml file containing the buttons
2) The parent activity file (TabActivity.java)
3) The activity file to reflect the change ( complainResponse.java)

Here is the code:
    LodgeComplaintFragment.java

```
ArrayList<String>userSelectedOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
 if(btnSis.getCurrentTextColor()==Color.BLUE){
userSelectedOptions.add("SIS");
 }
 Button but = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    .....   
    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        buttonListener.onMakeBookingButtonPressed(userSelectedOptions);
    }
});

    TabMainActivity.java
   public void onMakeBookingButtonPressed(ArrayList<String> list) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(TabMainActivity.this,  

                     complainResponse.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("userSelectOptions",list);
                startActivity(intent);
            }


 complainResponse.java
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.complainresponse);

    userInput = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("userSelectOptions");
    // Creates the window used for the UI

    if (userInput != null) {
        if (userInput.get(0) != null) {
            textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textview1.setText(userInput.get(0));
        }
    }

}
```

Error occurs at this line: 
      if (userInput != null) {
      //of complainResponse.java

Logcat:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Please help

Comment: THe bulk of the code have been omitted to allow for the relevant ones

Comment: You never put anything in the list.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the ArrayList that you pass to your activity.
I suspect this bit of code isn't being executed -

```
if(btnSis.getCurrentTextColor()==Color.BLUE){
  userSelectedOptions.add("SIS");    <------------ never gets here
}
```

To verify this, run the application in debug mode, and place a breakpoint at the `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

```
userInput.get(0) != null
```

this is the cause of error in my opinion, list can be initialized but empty.

instead you should use,

```
 if (!userInput.isEmpty())
```